# SearchFilter for multiple models -- Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using Django 3.2 with Restframework.
I'm trying for search filter and create a API with restframework which would output the searched term with its whole object.

I had a little success on that with [official doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter). But from that I can only search in a single Model and not as globally.
I found a [blog](https://yeti.co/blog/global-search-in-django-rest-framework/) on how to use multiple Models together?

I tried for following from that:

Views.py

```
class GlobalSearchList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GlobalSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
      query = self.request.query_params.get('query', None)
      users = MasterUser.objects.filter(Q(firstname__icontains=query) | Q(lastname__icontains=query) | Q(email__icontains=query) | Q(category__icontains=query))
      webinar = MasterWebinar.objects.filter(Q(host__icontains=query) | Q(title__icontains=query))
      section = ResourceSection.objects.filter(Q(resource_name__icontains=query))
      item = SectionItem.objects.filter(Q(item_title__icontains=query))
      all_results = list(chain(users,webinar,section,item))
      serialize_obj = serializers.serialize('json',all_results)
      print(serialize_obj)    #Json response is printed in console
      return JsonResponse(json.loads(serialize_obj), safe=False)   #nothing as output
```

In here, while printing the output it does print a json object, but doesn't return anything as output. Any cause why there is no output, where am I doing wrong?

serializers.py

```
class GlobalSearchSerializer(serializers.Serialize):
    
    def to_native(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, MasterIndividualMembers): 
            serializer = MasterIndividualMembersSerializer(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, MasterUser):
            serializer = MasterUserSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, MasterWebinar):
             serializer = MasterWebinarSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, MasterResource):
             serializer = MasterResourceSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, ResourceSection):
             serializer = ResourceSectionSerializer(obj)
         elif isinstance(obj, SectionItem):
             serializer = SectionItemSerializer(obj)

        else:
            raise Exception("Not found in any instance!")
        return serializer.data
```

Also I tried with `serializers.ModelSerializer` but it will only accept 1 model in serializer.
Any suggestions please!

**Edit:** On testing in Postman I received following output:

Endpoint:  localhost:8000/search/?query=john

```
[
    {}, {}
]
```

Expected outcome:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "password": "somehashcode",
        "last_login": "2021-07-13T06:08:08.313605Z",
        "email": "abc@xyz.com",
        "date_of_birth": "2020-10-10",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_admin": true,
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "is_member": true,
        "date_joined": "2021-07-11",
        "last_signed_in": "2021-07-11T03:27:37Z",
        "is_subscription": true,
        "category": null,
        "contact": "1231321",
        "membership_id": "343cr234rcrr3rc"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

To reproduce, console gives output:
`[<MasterUser: abc@xyz.com>, <MasterUser: dummy2@xyz.com>]`

As the firstname has John the whole `MasterUser` came as output.

Comment: In case your `serialized_obj` is the response you want, you may probably use something like this to return `return Response(serialized_obj, status=200`, `Response` comes from `from rest_framework.response import Response`. Does this work?

Comment: I tried that it throws error as ```The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.```

Comment: yes, it is giving this error because the method `get_querset` should be returning a `queryset` and not a response. Why are you trying to return a `serialized_obj` from this method?

Comment: Umm Iam not aware of ```get_queryset``` much, on how it works. But Since the ```all_results``` give a output of model's object only, I serialized them and trying to get the output. Any suggestions how can I modify this, or any document that can help?

Comment: What happens if you remove/comment the three lines after `all_results = chain(...)` and just add a line `return all_results'. Does it work as expected?

Comment: That was the first attempt to just return ```all_results``` but it gives blank output as well, but on debugging I saw model objects were returning, so I had to use serializers.

Comment: can you post what you are getting there? also, please add what you expect it to be?

Comment: Edit the post with expected and current output. And at bottom has the output of console upon calling ```print(all_results)```

Comment: I think the issue with the `serializer` and not with your `view`, probably. You can't raise an exception in `to_native` method. Please try to use `breakpoint` or `print` and check the type of `obj` inside this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I get rid of `class GlobalSearchList(generics.ListAPIView):` and also its serializers.

and just add response as `return HttpResponse(serialize_obj,content_type='application/json')` to receive json response.